# How to put a figure inside a shadowbox?

Tags: floats, boxes

I'm trying to put a figure inside a shadowbox with caption, I want the following result:

[image: The result]

I tried with these codes but I don't get the result, can anyone help me?

Which code can generate the plot?

```
\shadowbox{
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{frog.jpg}
    \caption{Phantom figure}
\end{figure}}


\begin{framed}
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{frog.jpg}
  \captionof{figure}{This is foo.}
  \label{fig:foo}
\end{center}
\end{framed}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your code so people can compile it.  Right now, people have to guess what class you are using, which packages are needed for that code, how `\shadowbox` is defined, how `framed` is defined etc. I know you must be loading `capt-of` or `caption`, but not which, and `graphicx`. No idea about the rest. Don't specify the extension when you `\includegraphics`, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Floats *can not* be nested in boxes. See if the following solution is what you looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{center}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{12pt}
\shadowbox{\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{frog.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{Phantom figure}
           }}
    \end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

or as float:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{12pt}
\shadowbox{\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{frog.jpg}
\caption{Phantom figure}
           }}
\end{figure}
```